# Expression is not a method error when trying to change the allignment of text using a button

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a project for school to change the alignment of text in a `TextBox` from left to right.

My Code:

```
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub cmdChangeAllignment_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdChangeAllignment.Click
        txtChangeAllignment.TextAlign.Right()
   End Sub
End Class
```

Results in the exception `Expression is not a method`. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextAlign` is a property that you set to change the alignment, so you should assign `HorizontalAlignment.Right` to it. `HorizontalAlignment.Right` is just a value in the enumeration, not a method; the reason your code *looks* like it should work is because static members can still be accessed through instances (which I think was a  really silly idea ).

```
txtChangeAllignment.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
```

Answer (score 1):

One bit of clarification on this for the OP...

The .NET API includes a ton of properties that dictate things like text alignments, control alignments, colors, and such, and typically the valid values for those kinds of things are too complicated to specify with text or strings, and end up just being represented with a bunch of magic numbers. Rather than expecting developers to remember the numbers, they've been rolled up and organized into a series of named, defined values called *enumerations* that *look* and operate kinda like properties themselves. "`HorizontalAlignment`" is one of them, with `Left`, `Right`, and `Center` the valid values.

Sorry if this is overkill given qwzjk's answer, but some of us are accustomed to the notion of enumerations, but a newcomer might not, so the hope is that it offers a little extra clarification for you.